# Freezing issues after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: 19.04, freeze

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 -> 18.10 and 19.04 since I had problems with Ubuntu crashing/hard freezing, especially with lock screen or after sleeping.

The lock screen hard crashes are gone, but I have plenty of other issues instead.

In particular, every time I drag to open the "lock" screen it gets stuck and seems frozen, half way for 30-60 seconds before finally getting into Ubuntu (see image)

[image]

Also, whenever I create a new text file and save it for the first time, the GUI freezes completely for 30-60 seconds as well, before going back to normal. The same thing happens when saving a screen shot from the screenshot app, so it seems there is some problem with disk access? However, when saving to an existing file, there is no delay.

Any ideas what could cause these issues or how I can try to debug it?

Basic system info from the "About" tab:

```
Ubuntu 19.04
Memory: 15.4 GiB
Intel Core i7 8550U CPU @ 1.80 GHz x 8
Graphics Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
Gnome 3.32.1
Os type 64-bit
Disk 512,1 GB
```

Comment: To check if it is not cause by errors from upgrading, could you use a live version of 19.04 and see if the freezing still happens.

Comment: Changing the desktop environment from Gnome to Mate made most of these issues disappear. The system still gets slow after running for a while, which is fixed by rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether this thread has relevance to the issue you're experiencing: [Ubuntu 19.04 freezes on writing to disk SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135547/ubuntu-19-04-freezes-on-writing-to-disk-ssd/1184619#1184619)

I posted a version of this answer there too. I think I was having the same problem as you, or a very similar one. Here were some things I noticed:

- Freezing tended to get worse (system would hang for longer) after it had been running for a while
- Commonly would hang for several seconds on resuming from suspend, saving a downloaded file to my desktop in Firefox, closing a file selection dialog (for example, to upload an email attachment or open a document) -- and would hang regardless of whether I actually opted to access a file or cancel the dialog
- After a day of simple web work and a few suspend/resume cycles, my system would feel sluggish in ways not at all justified by my hardware (brand new system, SSD, 8th gen i7, 16 GB RAM, this should not be bogged down by word processing and Gmail)
- Problem was totally nonexistent prior to upgrading to 19.04 from 18.10

I have now upgraded to 19.10 and the problem is less apparent. Immediately after upgrade, the hang reduced to less than a second instead of several seconds -- my system still did seem to hang slightly, but not in a way that I minded so much.

HOWEVER, I also tend to keep a lot of files on my desktop -- we're talking at least 60-200 at any given time. Many of them are small, but some are quite large (a Linux ISO, for example). On a hunch, I cleaned all these files off of my desktop, and the hang totally seems to have disappeared now. I would imagine that, even under 19.04, cleaning my desktop would have helped with this issue, at least a little bit, but I'm not about to revert to test this hypothesis.

I'm curious whether upgrading to 19.10 and/or cleaning the desktop has helped anyone else with similar issues.